# Change attribute of div when empty jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to check in loop if element is empty or not. When empty change its height to 0px, otherwise to 50px. I have something like this but this does not work.

```
$("div.start").each(function(){
    if($(this).html() == ''){
        $("div.new").css('height', '0px');
    }
    else{
        $("div.new").css('height', '50px');
    }
})
```

Comment: You should use `$(this)` throughout the inner code, or you'll be changing any div that has `class="new"`. You need to run this code whenever div content changes. When does that happen? It's something you yourself are in control of, you should be able to simply call the above code each time it happened.

Comment: I did `$(this).add("div.new").css('height', '0px')` but still does not work.

Comment: `$(this).css('height', $(this).html() == '' ? '0px' : '50px');` should do the trick, and saves the if block. Not sure where the `.add()` is coming from? Don't you want to change existing divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without your html, that will be ok:  if you want to eliminate spaces, add `$.trim` function

```
$("div.start div.new").each(function(){
        if($(this).html() == ''){
           $(this).css('height', '0px');
        }else{
           $(this).css('height', '50px');
        }
})
```

i think you could test too with:

```
if( $(this).is(':empty') )
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you should write the condition, whether it is empty or not, like this:

```
$('div.err:not(:empty)').css('height', '0px');
```

Comment: What is an err?

Comment: this is the syntax used to tell if it is empty or not